# problems with chromium installation

Tags: software-installation, chromium

I tried to install chromium with this command:

```
sudo apt-get install chromium-browser
```

But I got an error that the package is not available.

Can you please help me to download chromium?

Comment: Raspbian Jessie dropped the Chromium dependency. You can install it by following [this guide](http://conoroneill.net/running-the-latest-chromium-45-on-debian-jessie-on-your-raspberry-pi-2/)

Answer (score 1):

I found I had to manually fetch and install the packages.  The link the commentor provided didn't quite work for me.  I ended up with the following script:

https://gist.github.com/Rio517/48e88687513ac3b6ae1482e54ec0f22e

```
#Install Chromium Browser

wget https://www.dropbox.com/s/emv1akq9lm4gi3c/chromium-browser-l10n_50.0.2661.102-0ubuntu0.14.04.1.1118_all.deb?dl=0
wget https://www.dropbox.com/s/12ht1lgpossgq0q/chromium-browser_50.0.2661.102-0ubuntu0.14.04.1.1118_armhf.deb?dl=0
wget https://www.dropbox.com/s/041d46qhi9yhla7/chromium-codecs-ffmpeg-extra_50.0.2661.102-0ubuntu0.14.04.1.1117_armhf.deb?dl=0
sudo dpkg -i chromium-browser_50.0.2661.102-0ubuntu0.14.04.1.1118_armhf.deb?dl=0
sudo dpkg -i chromium-codecs-ffmpeg-extra_50.0.2661.102-0ubuntu0.14.04.1.1117_armhf.deb?dl=0
sudo dpkg -i chromium-browser-l10n_50.0.2661.102-0ubuntu0.14.04.1.1118_all.deb?dl=0

# add source for updates
wget -qO - http://bintray.com/user/downloadSubjectPublicKey?username=bintray | sudo apt-key add -
echo "deb http://dl.bintray.com/kusti8/chromium-rpi jessie main" | sudo tee -a /etc/apt/sources.list

#add flash
wget https://www.dropbox.com/s/enjmq0cjusw91w2/flash21.tar.xz?dl=0
tar -xJf flash21.tar.xz?dl=0
cd pepper
sudo cp *.so /usr/lib/chromium-browser/plugins
sudo cp *.json /usr/lib/chromium-browser/plugins
cd
sudo sh -c 'echo "CHROMIUM_FLAGS=\"${CHROMIUM_FLAGS} --ppapi-flash-path=/usr/lib/chromium-browser/plugins/libpepflashplayer.so --ppapi-flash-version=21.0.0.182-r1 -password-store=detect -user-data-dir\"" >  /etc/chromium-browser/customizations/01-pepper'
```